# Swift : Anchor SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, skspritenode

I am trying to replicate a popular look you get on music applications where you'll see a series of Sound Bars moving up and down to the beat of the music. My issue is that i am not able to get my sound bar to keep its bottom border anchored to the bottom of the screen and just adjust its height. My algorithm for the scaling is correct and it works great, but my issue is that my sound bar moves up and down the screen as opposed to sticking to the bottom and just adjusting its height. Here is what i have.

```
func setUpSoundBars(){
    //I have this as a skspritenode because i need to adjust its Z position
    //"SoundBars" is just a red background image sized to the iphone6 plus
    soundbar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SoundBars")
    self.addChild(soundbar!)
}

//updateBeatParticle() is being called constantly by CADisplayLink
func updateBeatParticle(){

//Algorithm to get scale according to music
//DO NOT WORRY ABOUT Below
//-------------------------------------------------------
    if let audio = backgroundMusic?.backgroundAudio {

        var scale: CGFloat = 0

        if (audio.playing) { // Only do this if the audio is actually playing
            audio.updateMeters() // Tell the audio player to update and fetch the latest readings

            let channels = audio.numberOfChannels

            var power: Float = 0
            //Loop over each channel and add its average power
            for i in 0..<channels {
                power += audio.averagePowerForChannel(i)
            }
            power /= Float(channels) // This will give the average power across all the channels in decibels

            // Convert power in decibels to a more appropriate percentage representation
            scale = CGFloat(getIntensityFromPower(power))
            scale -= 0.6
            if scale < 0 {
                scale = 0
            }
            scale *= 2
        }
//----------------------------------------------------
    //DO NOT WORRY ABOUT ABOVE    

        //This is where sound bar is adjusted to the and its size is changed 
        //to match the beat of the music
        //WHERE I NEED HELP!
        if let view = self.view {
            let height: CGFloat = view.frame.height * scale

            soundbar?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.height - height)
            soundbar?.size = CGSize(width: (self.view?.bounds.width)! * 0.20, height: height)
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to modify the `yScale` of the *SKSpriteNode*.

If for example you take a vertical bar image and set:

```
soundbar.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

You can simply scale the y-axis it to modify the height and it will not move positions.

```
soundbar.yScale = 2
```

In your case I'm sure this could be tied nicely into your existing scale calculations.